# pydev - setting up an existing python27 project complete with dlls and nested source folders in eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I am trying to set up a project in Eclipse Indigo with pydev on windows 7 Pro SP1  x64. The project exists in my drive (downloaded via tortoise svn) and has the following structure :

```
root\
 launcher.pyw
 settings.ini
 modules\
  __init__.py
  module1.py
  module2.py
  ...
  more_modules\
   __init__.py
   moduleA.py
   moduleB.py
   ...
  compiled\
   1.dll
   2.dll
   ...
```

I have successfully imported the project in eclipse - specifying root/ as the project folder -  and when I right click on the launcher.pyw and run the file the program runs alright (it is a gui application). I have 2 (main) issues :

1. I want to be able to run the project normally (tell eclipse that when I run the project I actually mean run the launcher.pyw) - when I right click on the project > Run as > Python-unit-test is the only option
2. I have, say, in more_modules\moduleA.py something like `from .. import module1` which shows as an error - so how should I set it up correctly ?

Not sure about the dlls folder also - and not sure about the code analysis - aparently I have to open a file to see the errors - but those belong to another question maybe

The project sourceforge page is : http://oblivionworks.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oblivionworks/Programs/Wrye%20Bash/

The root/ is Mopy/

**Edit**: moved the picture from my comment:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding launching, you can simply open the file and press F9 to run it. After that, if you've set to rerun the last launch in the preferences (see instructions at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html), you can simply press Ctrl+F11 to rerun it.

I took a look at your sf page and noted you didn't commit the .project and .pydevproject files (please do, so that anyone using PyDev can get things configured directly).

Regarding your import error in the code analysis, it'd be nice if you can actually provide the real example (from your description the error is that you have a '.py' in the end of the module that probably shouldn't be there, but it may be just a description... if it runs and code-analysis doesn't get it, please create a project with that use case and attach it in a bug-report in the pydev sf tracker).

As for the code analysis, usually you really have to open a file to see errors, but you can also right-click a folder and choose pydev > code analysis and it'll do a code-analysis for all the files beneath that folder that are a part of your pythonpath.

Comment: Can you also post the image for the project source folder (i.e.: right click project > properties > pydev - pythonpath) -- it's really strange that your icons in the pydev package explorer don't seem to be what they should if they were under a source folder. Note that you can add images to your question in stackoverflow.

Comment: I had the Mopy\bash\ and Mopy\bash\games\ in the path initially but it did not help - this was when I removed everything from the path. [Here](http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=9145868from..importErrorPydev2.jpg) is how it looks with [Mopy\bash\ in the path](http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=6006149PATHpyDev.jpg). The error reads "Unresolved import".  Adding Mopy\bash\games\ does not make a difference. I know about adding images - will do once this is resolved (you are welcome to do so in your answer) - Thanks :)

Comment: Well - someone went ahead and actually posted the .project and .pydevproject at the repo - could you check if those are right ? I think not : http://oblivionworks.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oblivionworks?view=revision&revision=2379. Thanks :)

Comment: Submitted a bug report - please have a look : https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3566615&group_id=85796&atid=577329